# Topology is to semi-decidability, coarse structures are to what?

Tags: lo.logic, gn.general-topology, computability-theory, coarse-geometry

There is a folklore correspondence between topology as semi-decidability amongst computer scientists, which is explained in places like:

1. [The monograph Synthetic Topology: of Data Types and Classical Spaces](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066104051357)
2. [An answer by Andrej Bauer on reversing the order of quantifiers](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4473/techniques-for-reversing-the-order-of-quanti%ef%ac%81ers/4478#4478)
   .

I recently also learnt that [Coarse structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarse_structure) are a type of "dual" to topologies, in that they capture "global" behaviour versus "local" behvaiour that topologies capture. This viewpoint is explained in:

- [This answer on MathOverflow to the question "dualizing topology"](https://mathoverflow.net/a/346748/123769), which writes down the topology axioms using category theory and then dualizes the construction.
- In general, the view appears to be held that Coarse Stuctures is the correct way to dualize a topology to study large-scale phenomena. My understanding is that it was used very effectively by Gromov to study hyperbolic groups by considering quasi-isometry.

So, it is natural to ask, "what is the computational equivalent of a coarse structure"? I was hoping the answer would be something like "co-induction" / "making progress", since topology seems to be about "deciding" things. However, I have no clue how to *proceed* with such a question. I'd love some insight into this.

Comment: @YCor, I think your edit changed the meaning of the title.  Perhaps the SAT-style analogy [notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogy#Identity_of_relation) is unfamiliar?  The original title, I think, was not expressing general bafflement as the current one seems to do, but asking "What is to coarse structures as semi-decideability is to topology?"  In case I am mistaken, I will leave it to @‌SiddharthBhat to revert.

Comment: @LSpice that was indeed the intention --- However, I was worried the title was too flippant / not well communicated. If the analogy notation is indeed well known, then I'd like to change it back!

Comment: Indeed the initial colons were cryptic to me; the OP's new title looks good.